# Multiple Laravel apps on the same server / Scheduled tasks conflict

Tags: php, apache, laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have two sub domains on the same server, both are laravel 5.+ framework / Apache / PHP / Ubuntu:

> a.domain.com
>
> b.domain.com

When assigning a crontab command for each app:

```
* * * * * php /var/www/a/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
* * * * * php /var/www/b/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

it runs the first scheduler twice, what should I do to fix this conflict ?

Comment: So each app uses a different code base? Do they share any other resources?

Comment: Yes, they use a different code directory :
/var/www/A_app
/var/www/B_app